# Laravel + vue.js file upload put

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, form-data

I've successful uploaded files with `vue.js 1.0` like this (post request):

```
store () {
            this.storingMessage = true;
            var form = new FormData();
            form.append('subject', this.message.subject);
            form.append('message', this.message.message);
            form.append('topic_id', this.message.topic_id);

            for(var key in this.message.attachment) {
                form.append('attachment[' + key + ']', this.message.attachment[key]);
            }

            MessageService.store(this, form);
        }
```

But when I try to update files like this (put request):

```
update () {
            this.updatingMessage = true;
            var form = new FormData();
            form.append('subject', this.message.subject);
            form.append('message', this.message.message);
            form.append('slug', this.message.slug);

            for(var key in this.message.attachment) {
                form.append('attachment[' + key + ']', this.message.attachment[key]);
            }

            MessageService.update(this, form);
        }
```

And in my controller I `dd($request->all())` result is `[]`.

So why is it not working with `put`????!?!?!?

**Services:**

```
store (context, form) {
        return Vue.http.post('/api/message', form)
            .then(({data}) => {
                context.success();
            }, (error) => {
                context.error(error.data);
            });
    },

    update (context, form) {
        return Vue.http.put('/api/message/' + form.get('slug'), form)
            .then(({data}) => {
                context.success();
            }, (error) => {
                context.error(error.data);
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a [Laracast Discussion](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/vue-resource-patch-put-not-sending-the-data) it would seem there is a problem when using the put method and a formData object a way to avoid this is with method spoofing.

Try this instead, in your update method

```
let data = { _method : 'PATCH' , form : form}

return Vue.http.post('/api/message/' + form.get('slug'), data)
    .then(({data}) => {
        context.success();
    }, (error) => {
        context.error(error.data);
    });
```

your data in your controller will be available as `form` in this case

```
$request->form
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I'm using ```form data``` so I had to do it like this: ```form.append('_method', 'PUT');```